# How to handle large database updates with node js

Tags: mysql, update, node.js

I have a program which is time based. The users have all day to enter data that will affect their score, however if you haven't entered anything by midnight then your score is negatively affected. I had thought about setting up a chron job to handle this at midnight, but am then faced with a batch process that may be updating hundreds of thousands of records all at once.

I've decided one way to reduce this would be to divide the batch into 1000 records and then release the event loop, stack on another 1000. Is this a good way to go about something so massive? Would creating a second server instance and offloading the work to that server be a better idea?

Comment: Update of a big table can be invasive; I recommend 1K rows at a time, no "event loop", just a loop in the single cron job.  More on chunking: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide proof that 500k rows is a lot for your database.

**Hint** In most cases,  it isn't.

Although this answer could befit a Comment, this is a valid Answer.

Databases deal with MILLIONS of rows at a time without a hiccup.  500k is nothing.

Things you need to be aware of when testing the single DML approach

- Undo tablespace (or MySQL's equivalent)
- possibly temp tablespace (for indexes)
- locks on a heavily modified table.

If you have proof that one (or more) of those is causing issues, then you should consider Chunking your `UPDATE` statement.

You haven't given any indication that any of those is a problem.  So, the answer is:  Neither.  Use a single DML.

As far as "process on separate server"...I don't see the need.  I foresee too many headaches with synchronizing the processed rows with any modified data that occured during the Processing.

Comment: The complexity of the db updates is not what worries me, they are async. This is essentially a giant for loop and each of those calls takes time to begin and callback, which is why I asked if batching them was appropriate.

Comment: Processing 500k rows with a single `UPDATE` statement is faster than processing 1 row at a time in a `giant for loop`.  Even if the `UPDATE` is complex, store "what you want to do" in a scratch table ( via `INSERT..SELECT`) then do the `UPDATE` (other RDBMS would call it `MERGE`).  Basically, you want to do as much work as possible in every DML call.  Don't treat the database like a bit bucket by accessing every row individually.  Databases suck at doing that.